# How do I discover what content types a HTTP POST service allows?

Tags: http, post, content-type, content-negotiation

I am writing a client for [OpenTox webservices](http://www.opentox.org/dev/apis/api-1.2/), but several services they provide have optional support for certain MIME types with only a few obligatory, e.g. this [Dataset service](http://www.opentox.org/dev/apis/api-1.2/dataset#section-9). So I need to discover which of those content types are supported by a particular running service dynamically...

Now, for GET services I can use the "Accepts" HTTP header and when I POST content I can use "Content-type" to set what format I am sending in. But I rather not default into trial-and-error, as these data sets can be large. Therefore, I like to know up front the best MIME type I can use.

How do I perform content negotiation with POST services? I am using the [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/), but that is not important for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

POSTed Content negotiation is not enshrined in the HTTP specification; instead what is advisable is to use the [OPTIONS](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.2) method. This is exactly the case in the OpenTox framework: OPTIONS has to be implemented by all web services. The service returns an RDF document (according to the Accept Header you specify) and a WADL-like content, i.e. it returns machine-readable documentation specifying the available MIME types, the possible HTTP status codes etc. Unfortunately so far there's only one implementation of OPTIONS in OpenTox, namely [JAQPOT3](http://opentox.ntua.gr/19-articles/joomla/8-jaqpot3-central). Check out [this wiki entry](http://opentox.ntua.gr/wiki/OPTIONS_in_JAQPOT).